# Changing the order of occurrence of elements while using Schema extension

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am facing this issue with XSD extension  while calling an external web service. Their WSDL defines the output to something like this,

WSDL STRUCTURE

```
<wsdl:message name="customerHistoryInquiryResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="customerHistoryInquiryReturn" type="impl:customerHistoryResult"/>
</wsdl:message>

<complexType name="customerHistoryResult">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="impl:ServiceRequestResult">
            <sequence>
                <element name="accountName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="accountNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="application" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="paymentRecords" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOfPaymentSummary"/>
                <element name="premiseAddress" nillable="true" type="impl:Address"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType abstract="true" name="ServiceRequestResult">
    <sequence>
        <element name="excngStatus" nillable="true" type="impl:ExcngStatus"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="ExcngStatus">
    <sequence>
        <element name="statusCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="statusMessage" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="exchangeDateTime" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="exchangeId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

So, with the above response structure in WSDL, my web service client tool is expecting a XML response in this fashion,

EXPECTED RESPONSE

```
<customerHistoryInquiryResponse>
    <customerHistoryInquiryReturn>
        <ExcngStatus>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        </ExcngStatus>

        <accountName/>
        <accountNumber/>
        <application/>

        <paymentRecords>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        </paymentRecords>
        <premiseAddress>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        </premiseAddress>
    </customerHistoryInquiryReturn>
</customerHistoryInquiryResponse>
```

But when I make the web service call, the actual response from the service is not following its own WSDL structure. Service Response structure looks like this, with  element occurring at the end of the structure instead of coming at the top.

ACTUAL RESPONSE

```
<customerHistoryInquiryResponse>
    <customerHistoryInquiryReturn>      
        <accountName/>
        <accountNumber/>
        <application/>

        <paymentRecords>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        </paymentRecords>
        <premiseAddress>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        </premiseAddress>
        <ExcngStatus>
        ..
        ..
        ..
        </ExcngStatus>      
    </customerHistoryInquiryReturn>
</customerHistoryInquiryResponse>
```

My web service client throws an validation error saying "Expected 'ExcngStatus' element, instead received 'accountName' element.

I read about using  for extending XML Schemas and every document says that by using , additional elements will be ADDED to the baseType that is
 mentioned in base="", means the baseType will be EXTENDED with additional elements.

My question is/are, 
with the  WSDL Structure (given above), is there anything wrong in the EXPECTED RESPONSE (given above) ? 
Is there a way to specify the order of occurrence of elements while using extension
    '' ?
What changes can I do in the WSDL to SUCCESSFULLY VALIDATE  the ACTUAL RESPONSE (given above) ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your service providers xml service response does not comply with their own service definition!

From w3c: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivExt

> When a complex type is derived by extension, its effective content
>   model is the content model of the base type plus the content model
>   specified in the type derivation

It goes on with an example:

```
  <complexType name="Address">
    <sequence>
      <element name="name"   type="string"/>
      <element name="street" type="string"/>
      <element name="city"   type="string"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <complexType name="UKAddress">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="ipo:Address">
        <sequence>
          <element name="postcode" type="ipo:UKPostcode"/>
        </sequence>
        ....
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
<complexType name="UKAddress">
  <sequence>
    <!-- content model of Address -->
    <element name="name"   type="string"/>
    <element name="street" type="string"/>
    <element name="city"   type="string"/>

    <!-- appended element declaration -->
    <element name="postcode" type="ipo:UKPostcode"/>
  </sequence>
  ....
</complexType>
```

So you could try telling the service provider you're doing it wrong. Otherwise you're a bit stuck I reckon. Sorry cannot think of a suitable workaround.